# How can I find a specific string in a variable using re and change it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, variables, python-re

How can I find a specific string in a variable and change it with regular expressions
For example

```
import re
Variable_To_Change = "This is Variable Number ^NUMBER^"
```

How can I use RE to find the word ^NUMBER^ and change the variable so that it doesn't say ^NUMBER^ but actual number like "This is Variable Number 1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why would you use re for this... I dont know but here you go

```
 re.sub("\^NUMBER\^","1",my_string)
```

you could just use

```
 my_string.replace("^NUMBER^",1)
```

Im now going to make some assumtions

you have a data structure like follows

```
data = {"NUMBER":1,"STRING":"hello friend","BOOL":True}
```

and you have a string as follows

```
my_string = "I have ^NUMBER^ of apples to share with ^STRING^ and this is ^BOOL^"
```

and you want to substitute in the data from your data dictionary to the string

this can be done with `re` or `string.replace` quite easily (If you would have better defined the original question I would have left this to begin with)

```
# with replace
for key,value in data.items():
    my_string = my_string.replace("^{key}^".format(key=key),str(value))
print(my_string)

# with RE
def match_found(match):
    return data.get(match.group(1),"???UNKNOWN VAR???")
my_string = re.sub("\^([A-Z]+)\^",match_found,my_string
```